# Feedback loop design (buck converter): Output capacitance- effective value or nominal value to be considered?

Tags: capacitor, switch-mode-power-supply, filter, buck, compensation

In this [TI datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps62180.pdf?ts=1630521855553&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTPS62180) of TPS62180, it was mentioned that the LC filter combination should be selected from a set of predefined values. I understand this is usually  the case for an internally compensated converter.
[image]

1. **Why are the capacitor values specified in nominal value since effective capacitance is what matters finally? In the feedback loop design, we need to consider effective capacitance at the operating voltage, right?**
2. Why is the manufacturer so specific about x 47uF, as long as effective capacitance is met we can choose any value, right?

Comment: I am sure they mean nominal. By and large, capacitors with similar ratings have roughly similar de-ratings also. TI has tools that will allow you to analyze the loop stability with specific part numbers. Maybe check TI webbench.

Comment: This is because X7R caps have this tolerance with DC voltage decrease +/- initial tolerance so use much higher rated V

Comment: There is a big difference between 8 * 47uF capacitors, and one 376uF (390uF) capacitor, when you consider ESR. lead inductance, and PCB layout, in fast switching circuits. The datasheet is warning you that the internal design assumes the configuration shown : deviate from that and performance may be affected.

Answer (score 0):

Not all 47 uF ceramic Caps are the same, yet X series most common in this size of MLCC are +/-20% and drop 60% with rated DC voltage. This is normal.

Some are better.

ESR can also be low , soft termination for crack prevention and damped for low piezo microphonic/speaker effects.

[image] [image]

Also for C=2x47uF and L = 1uH the SRF series resonant frequency is 16 kHz

- which rises to 24 kHz if C drops 60%.
- So you do not want switching frequency ripple in your output
- final Rs & SRF are both important for damping AC to DC in choosing L, DCR , C and ESR along with RdsOn
- these affect final Q factor, control-loop step-load stability,  ripple power dissipation in the cap. and temp rise, MTBF, & efficiency.

This was not intended as an endorsement that [Samsung](http://weblib.samsungsem.com/mlcc/mlcc-ec.do) are best, just an example.